# Creating four columns using php loop in table

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make 4 column layout of table using php loop so it is conditional also. I am unable to create four columns as browser automatically inserts tr for tds without having trs. Maybe I am missing something...

my code

```
<?php $i=0; while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<?php if($i % 4){ echo "<tr>"; echo $i;} ?>
<td><?= $row['Zip_Code']?></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="zipcode[]" id="zip_<?= $row['Zip_Code']?>" value="<?= $row['Zip_Code']?>" <?php echo (in_array($row['Zip_Code'], $zipcodes))? 'checked':'';?> ><label class="zip_label" for="zip_<?= $row['Zip_Code']?>"></label></td>
<?php if($i % 4){ echo "</tr>"; } ?>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

My Desired output

```
<tr>
<td>blah </td>
<td>blah </td>
<td>blah </td>
<td>blah </td>
</tr>
```

but it shows me like this

```
<tr>
<td>blah </td>
<td>blah </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your desired output is actually 4 column, 1 row.  The browser has shown you a 2 column, 1 row table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you want to do:

```
<?php $i=0; while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<?php if($i % 2 == 0){ echo "<tr>";} ?>
<td><?= $row['Zip_Code']?></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="zipcode[]" id="zip_<?= $row['Zip_Code']?>" value="<?= $row['Zip_Code']?>" <?php echo (in_array($row['Zip_Code'], $zipcodes))? 'checked':'';?> ><label class="zip_label" for="zip_<?= $row['Zip_Code']?>"></label></td>
<?php if($i % 2 != 0){ echo "</tr>"; } ?>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

The output will be:

```
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="zipcode[]" id="zip_1" value="1" checked ><label class="zip_label" for="zip_1"></label></td>
<td>2</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="zipcode[]" id="zip_2" value="2" checked ><label class="zip_label" for="zip_2"></label></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="zipcode[]" id="zip_3" value="3" checked ><label class="zip_label" for="zip_3"></label></td>
<td>4</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="zipcode[]" id="zip_4" value="4" checked ><label class="zip_label" for="zip_4"></label></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Man! You rock! Logic! I was out of it!

Answer (score -1):

This should work;

```
$i = 1;

 echo "<tr>";
 while($i <= 10){

  echo '<td>' . $i . '</td>';

   $i++;
 }
 echo "</tr>;
```